# Javascript Time Comparison: What is the best way to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, date-format

Here I have a function which I use to calculate the difference between two Time variables, `start` and `end`, and display the output as 'Past', 'Current', or 'Future'.

I was able to calculate 'Current' and 'Future' values, but no luck with "Past'. Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jk6a/8/) and any help would be great.

On a side note, I do prefer a plugin-less way to achieve this.

```
//My Start time and End time
var start = "Mon Nov 22 2012 08:45:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";
var end = "Mon Nov 22 2012 10:15:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";

//Calling to test function
test(start, end);

//Function to calculate 
function test(startTime, endTime) {
    startTime= new Date(startTime);
    endTime= new Date(endTime);
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var difference = currentTime - startTime; 

    if (difference > 0 && currentTime > startTime) {
        alert ("Past!");
    } 

    if(startTime < currentTime && currentTime < endTime){ 
        alert("Current!");
    }

    if(difference < -1){
        alert("Future!");
    }
}​
```

Link to **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jk6a/8/)**

Comment: So... Past is when `start < end < current`, current is when `start < current < end`, and future is when `current < start < end`?

Comment: This makes little sense.

Comment: I don't see no stinkin' jQuery, we've been flim-flamed!!

Comment: You should not expect Date to consistently parse strings in all browsers, e.g. "Mon Nov 22 2012 08:45:00 GMT+0800" can be considered an invalid date, so conforming browsers will return `NaN`, others will ignore the incorrect day and return a date object for Thursday, 22 Nov 2012. Break it up and manually parse it, then you'll get consistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh!! I just need some sleep. It's **working** and here's the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jk6a/9/

Thanks everyone who helped.

```
//My Start time and End time
var start = "Mon Nov 23 2012 08:45:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";
var end = "Mon Nov 23 2012 10:15:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";

//Calling to test function
test(start, end);

//Function to calculate 
function test(startTime, endTime) {
    startTime= new Date(startTime);
    endTime= new Date(endTime);
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var difference = currentTime - startTime; 

    if (startTime < endTime && endTime < currentTime) {
        alert ("Past!");
    } 

    if(startTime < currentTime && currentTime < endTime){ 
        alert("Current!");
    }

    if(currentTime < startTime && startTime < endTime){
        alert("Future!");
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the values of `someDate.getTime()`, as it will give you an integer representing the unix epoch (time ellapsed since 1/1/1970), wich will be comparable and substractable.

I edited the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jk6a/12/

Cheers

Comment: There is no need for `getTime`, using a date object for arithmetic operations effectively calls it anyway (incidentally, the time value is UTC, not that it makes any difference here).

Answer (score 0):

This is redundant:

```
 var difference = currentTime - startTime; 

 if (difference > 0 && currentTime > startTime)
```

Given the assignment, `difference > 0` and `currentTime > startTime` are testing exactly the same condition.  If one is true the other will always also be true, so there is no reason to test both.

Really, all you need is this:

```
if (startTime > endTime) {
   throw "Invalid range: end precedes start";
}

if (startTime < currentTime) {
    if (endTime < currentTime) {
         alert("Past");
    } else {
         alert("Current");
    }
} else {
  alert ("Future");
}
```